# Hello! Coul someone explain why this code gets an error " ValueError: too many values to unpack"?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
available_items = {"health potion": 10, "cake of the cure": 5, "green elixir": 20, "strength sandwich": 25, "stamina grains": 15, "power stew": 30}
health_points = 20

for key,value in available_items:
  health_points += value
print(health_points)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 7, in 
    for i,j in available_items:
 ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for key,value in available_items.items():
    #...
```

`for key,value in available_items` alone will only iterate keys.